# Vector of triangle

Tags: vectors

[image: Question]

Please explain how to get answer. Regards!

Comment: You can set up cartesian coordinates satisfying $O=(0,0),\, B=(x_b,0),\, A=(x_a,y_a)$ and calculate everything.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?

Comment: Really I cannot solve this.... Can you give step-by-step guide pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking vectors with origin O, we have that P is the point $\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})$ since it is the midpoint of AB. Hence Q is the point $\frac{3}{8}(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})$. R is the point $k\mathbf{b}$ and A is obviously the point $\mathbf{a}$. The general point on the line through A and R is $\lambda\mathbf{a}+(1-\lambda)k\mathbf{b}$. So to get Q we must take $\lambda=\frac{3}{8}$, so we need $\frac{3}{8}=k(1-\lambda)=k\frac{5}{8}$, and hence $k=\frac{3}{5}$.